# Show formula of a cell, but values instead of references

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a formula to show a cells formula in another cell.

I want to show the values of each reference in this formula, instead of the reference.

> > Ex:
>
> =$R$16+R19*($T$15-$R$16)
>
> > Want it to be
> >
> > =3+2*(4-2)

Function I am using now to show formula as it is

```
Function GetFormula(Cell As Range) As String
   GetFormula = Cell.Formula
End Function
```

Comment: Not sure how to do this, but just wanted to get some clarification, how would you handle issues like ranges of more then 1 cell or volatile functions?

Comment: Will the formula contain only single-cell references all from the same worksheet?

Comment: Yes, ranges will probably make it hard, but say it's only single-cell references.

Comment: A couple things you can experiment with: If you manually select each cell reference in turn and press F9 the value of the target will resolve. That will precisely match your desired output, but it's a manual process. In VBA you can walk through the Precedents of a formula cell, and display things like the target address and value of each precedent. How to integrate this output with the original formula seems much trickier.

Comment: And like tim asked, will they be from the same sheet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very basic example which can handle cases like

```
=B1+C1-D1/E1
=$B$1+C1*($B$1-$D$1)
=B1+C1-(D1/E1)
=B1+C1-(D1/E1)
=$B$1*C1*($B$1/$D$1)
```

**Assumptions:**

1. Let's say the above formulas are in cell A1 to A5
2. All cells are in the same sheet
3. There is no worksheet function like SUM, Vlookup etc
4. No Error handling done. Assuming that you will take care of it

**Sample Worksheet**

[image]

**Code**:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        Debug.Print ConvertToValues(Range("A" & i))
    Next i
End Sub

Function ConvertToValues(rng As Range)
    Dim sTmp As String, sOpr As String, sOrig As String
    Dim s As String, v As String
    Dim MyAr
    Dim i As Long

    sOpr = "+,/,-,*,&,(,),{,},[,]"

    MyAr = Split(sOpr, ",")

    sTmp = Replace(rng.Formula, "$", "")
    sOrig = sTmp

    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        sTmp = Replace(sTmp, MyAr(i), "SIDROUT")
    Next i

    MyAr = Split(sTmp, "SIDROUT")

    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        s = MyAr(i)

        If Len(Trim(s)) <> 0 Then
            v = Range(s).Value
            sOrig = Replace(sOrig, s, v)
        End If
    Next i

    If sOrig <> "" Then _
    ConvertToValues = "=" & sOrig
End Function
```

**Output**

[image]

**Note**:

Let me know if the above code fails in a particular scenario and I will update the code.

Comment: Nice one! In RL "SIDROUT" would be a variable or const in my code.

Comment: `SIDROUT` here is a delimiter.

Comment: I know. That's why I would have a var called "tempDelimiter". Two reasons: self-explanatory code and less prone to a typo mistake.

Comment: Yup you can use a Const Variable and set it to `SIDROUT` or `JULIUSZ` :)

Comment: Perfect, I used your Formula to answer a question from an OP today.