# Show formula with values instead of reference in EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have similar problem as described in this topic:
[Show formula of a cell, but values instead of references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556406/show-formula-of-a-cell-but-values-instead-of-references)

But I need to show as in

[image: as in this picture]

formulas directly in excel sheet. Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the answer from that other question? You need to show that you've made an attempt to solve this yourself.  (See the **[tour]** as well as **"[ask]"**.) Also, are the formulas always going to be 4 cells referenced? Can you show the formulas in the cells, in addition to what you've tried?

Comment: So what is the issue with the code in the link you provided? It does exactly what you asked for. If not please clarify where exactly your difficulty is.

Comment: Also please always include **exactly** the code **you** actually used within your question (use the [edit] button to add it). Links to similar codes don't help to find **your** issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @SiddharthRout Function...
First; Place the `Function` as a module in your workbook. Under the Developers Tab, select `Insert_Module`, Copy and paste the Function.
Second; Save the below sub in the Project window in your `ThisWorkbook` folder...

```
Sub ShowFormulValues()
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("B1:B" & lRow).Formula = "=ConvertToValues(A1)"
End Sub
```

Run `ShowFormulValues` and Sid's Formula will provide the information you want.