# How can I extract the values in a cell formula reference - Office 365

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have a formula like so:

```
=H6*(1-K10)*(1-K11)*(K12)*(1-K13)*(1-K14)*K15*K16
```

which translates to (and this is my end result):

```
= 0.3 * (1-0.2) * (1-0.9) * (0.5) * (1-0.1) * (1-0.8) * 0.2 * 1.0
```

I see from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556406/show-formula-of-a-cell-but-values-instead-of-references) that I can use VBA to extract the actual values. But, I am hoping to avoid a VBA solution.

Is there anyway without using VBA to create a formula with those hard coded values *instead of* their references?

Comment: I cannot see a way to do it using formula given the endless combinations of calculations/formulas and variations of cell references not to mention what if there is a range used... I would give a vote to `vba` unless you are ready to manually select each cell reference in the formula and press **F9** repeatedly to convert each reference to the value behind...

Answer (score 0):

## Use the `Name Manager` in Excel

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-name-manager-in-excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4

1. Click `Name Manager`
2. Click `New...`
3. Set `Name`, e.g. `myFunc`
4. Set `Refers To` as `=sheet1!$H$6*(1-sheet1!$K$10)*(1-sheet1!$K$11)*sheet1!$K$12*(1-sheet1!$K$13)*(1-sheet1!$K$14)*sheet1!$K$15*sheet1!$K$16`
5. Write in a cell, e.g. `A1`, with `=myFunc`

## With VBA

Write the function in a VBA normal module

```vb
Function myFunc()
    myFunc = 0.3 * (1-0.2) * (1-0.9) * (0.5) * (1-0.1) * (1-0.8) * 0.2 * 1.0
End Function
```

Use the `myFunc` in a cell

`=myFunc()`

Comment: _ But, I am hoping to avoid a VBA solution._. Additionally, that doesn't extract values from a sheet formula, it is hard coded...

Comment: But I still need to manually write that out at least once...?